# New lines HTML if value changed in MySql Output via PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is the HTML/PHP , I am using to display some data.

```
 <body>
        <section>
            <h1>Facebook Search</h1>
            <!-- TABLE CONSTRUCTION-->
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Comment</th>
                    <th>Comment Made By</th>
                    <th>Commentor's Profile Link</th>
                    <th>Comment ID</th>
                    <th>Post ID</th>
                    
                </tr>
                <!-- PHP CODE TO FETCH DATA FROM ROWS-->
                <?php   // LOOP TILL END OF DATA 
                    while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                 ?>
                <tr>
                    <!--FETCHING DATA FROM EACH 
                        ROW OF EVERY COLUMN-->
                    <td><?php echo $rows['comtext'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['comby'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['compro'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['commentid'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['postid'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    }
                 ?>
            </table>
        </section>
    </body>
      
    </html>
```

and I am getting the data like this from the `db`.

```
$sql = "SELECT comments.*, posts.postid FROM comments JOIN posts USING(postid)";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$mysqli->close();
```

This outputs a single table with all the data. My question is , is there a way to break the single table into tables when the value of `postid` changes? It goes like..is 1 for x number of rows, then 2 for x number of rows and so on. I wanted to have a little break between those tables.

Comment: Yes, remember the `postid` in a variable, when it changes ... close the table and start another table

Comment: Yes why not? What do you think would be the problem with that? Have you tried to think how you could break it up? As alluded to above the logic would not be complex. You already know how to loop through the data, and you already know how to get the post ID, so you're most of the way there, really. Asking here is fine but it's not a substitute for some initial effort on your part.

Comment: I can check for the value of the `postid` , but I don't know how to write the `html` part of it, Will try to find out.

Comment: Well you already know how to write the html for a table, it's right there in your current code, so again, that's another building block you've already got in place

Comment: I meant, from the check, inside the `while` of the `php` where to put the `html` of the `table`

Comment: It's not really clear specifically what you're uncertain about, to be honest, that description is pretty vague. Try to implement the logic RiggsFolly described. If you get stuck, update your question with your attempt and explain what still isn't working.

Comment: I am uncertain about the placement of the `HTML` table code vis-a-vis the check for the value of `postid` . Will update a failed attempt, if I can find it.

Comment: You use the value of the postid to decide what html to echo - whether to close the table and open a new one, or not. Then after that you just carry on with the next row as normal. It's a fairly simple if statement. Not really sure what you are trying to say about "placement" exactly. That's why we need to see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to break the single table into tables when the value of postid changes

You should stop using "SELECT *", it's inefficient and makes code difficult to maintain. While we're talking about style here, you swap back and forth between PHP and inline HTML which also impacts the readability of your code.

As to your question...

You need to ensure that the output of your query is sorted by postid - or you're going to get a lot of tables.

Use a state variable to track the postid from the previous iteration of the loop.

```
$prev=0;
while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
   if ($rows['postid']!=$prev) {
      close_table();
      open_table();
      $prev=$rows['postid'];
   }
   output_row($rows);
}
close_table();
```

The problem with this is that each iteration of the expects that you've already written `<table>` to the output stream - including the first iteration. You could do this before the loop - but you'll end up with an empty table at the top of the page. You could add another state variable to track whether you have opened a table tag yet. Personally, I'd go with making inferences from the value of the existing state variable:

```
$prev=0;
while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
   if ($rows['postid']!=$prev) {
      $prev || close_table();
      open_table();
      $prev=$rows['postid'];
   }
   output_row($rows);
}
close_table();
```

(the || is a quick way of writing if (not(condition)) do something() )

Note that unless you fix the size of the columns, then each table will be independently sized to fit the data that resides within it.

Comment: I am just starting out with MySQL with multiple tables, that's why the code is like that. Thanks for your help.